# S3 class in r into proportions

Tags: r, proportions

I need to turn the object containing a dataframe into an S3 class. And then I need to write a summary method showing the proportions of subjects for every level of each variable. Any tips on how to do this? I am really new to R and have no idea how to go about this.

Thanks

I tried dataframe1 <- class(dataframe)

which came up as [1] dataframe

I have no idea how to go about the proportions then

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new type of S3 object simply by assigning an extra name to an existing object's `class` attribute. Since we only want this to work on data frames, we can specify our S3 creator function like this:

```r
proportion <- function(x) {
  if(!inherits(x, "data.frame")) {
    stop("'proportion' requires a data frame as input")
  }
  structure(x, class = c("proportion", class(x)))
}
```

However, we also need a summary function that will create a summary of proportions for each column. Here, we can simply use `table` for each column, divided by the column's length:

```r
summary.proportion <- function(x) {
  x <- lapply(x, function(a) structure(c(table(a))/length(a), class = "Dlist"))
  structure(x, class = "proportion_summary")
}
```

Finally, we want a print method for the summary object:

```r
print.proportion_summary <- function(x, ...) {
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    cat("Column", i, "is", names(x)[i], "with the following proportions:\n")
    print(x[[i]])
    cat("\n")
  }
  invisible(x)
}
```

Now if we have the following data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(animal = c("fish", "fish", "cat", "cat", "dog"),
                 colour = c("gold", "white", "gray", "black", "gold"))
```

We can convert it into a proportion object like this:

```r
prop <- proportion(df)
```

And though it looks like a normal data frame:

```r
prop
#>   animal colour
#> 1   fish   gold
#> 2   fish  white
#> 3    cat   gray
#> 4    cat  black
#> 5    dog   gold
```

We can see it has a nice summary method showing the proportions we wanted:

```r
summary(prop)
#> Column 1 is animal with the following proportions:
#> cat                     0.4
#> dog                     0.2
#> fish                    0.4
#> 
#> Column 2 is colour with the following proportions:
#> black                   0.2
#> gold                    0.4
#> gray                    0.2
#> white                   0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>